# What is the implication if the resultsets of a java application is not being closed?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have an old java application (I am not the developer) and result sets of that application is not being closed. From time to time I am getting an error from the application (exceeded max java heap space etc..) and it causes a downtime.

sometimes the error is (The connection is closed) I know that this is because the connection cursor is already full. connections also not being closed (I am now working on it)

My Question is: Is the resultset issue possibly causes the heap space error?

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major issue here is the connections not being closed. ResultSets are closed when the Statement that returned them are closed, and Statements are closed when the connection that created them are closed, but unless the connection is closed everything will leak. This includes both memory and locks at the database, and whatever other database resources apply to an open Statement or ResultSet.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. I think that is what happening. I am already working on the connection issue.

Comment: This does assume that the driver implementation behaves according to the specification, and that it correctly cleans up on `close()` (eg remove cached rows)

Answer (score 0):

Every object should be closed after its use is over.
use `finally` block after your `catch` block to close your opened connections. even if there is an exception JVM will execute your `finally` block.